# Selecting all messages to user from conversation in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a "message" system for users whose data scheme looks something like this:

```
Table: Messages - Message_id PRI AI key
Message_id    Message_text   From_user_id   Date   Conversation_ID
1                  'a'            1                     1               
2                  'b'            2                     1
3                  'c'            5                     1
4                  'f'            18                    2
5                  'e'            1                     8

Table:Conversations
Conversation_id   Subject   
1                 'random'
2                  'hi'
8                  'yolo'

Table:Participants
Conversation_ID   User_id   Ignored - TINYINT(1)
      1            1            0                  
      1            2            0
      1            5            1
      2            18           0
      2            223          0
      8            1            0
      8            19           0
```

How it works is that every conversation has its own id, and any messages under that conversation are recorded into messages with the column conversation_id relating the message to the conversation. A user can "ignored" a conversation, thus in the participants, we have a TINYINT column for figuring out whether or not the user has ignored the conversation.

I'm trying to get a query that can return first the conversation row, then below it the messages in the conversation and these are all specific towards the querying user. The where clause should also be that the user did not ignored the conversation. So if we want to find the "conversations" along with the corresponding messages for User_id 1 the return result would be something like this:

```
Conversation_id   Subject   Message_id   Message_text   From_user_id
      1          'random'      null         null            null
      1                         1            'a'               1
      1                         2            'b'               2
      1                         3            'c'               5
      8            'yolo'     null          null              null   
                                5            'e'               1
```

Essentially in psuedo-code, what I'm trying to do is:

```
SELECT conversation_id, conversations.subject FROM participants WHERE user_id = '1' AND ignored = 0 LEFT JOIN conversations ON conversations.conversation_id = participants.conversation_id AND participants.ignored = 0
UNION GROUP BY messages.conversation_id
SELECT message_id, message_text, from_user_id FROM messages WHERE messages.conversation_id = conversation.conversation_id
```

Unfortunately, I've been having difficulty with the UNION group by because I can't just mash all the grows together. I've been trying to do this in one query (so selecting null to make up for the fact that conversations doesn't have message_text and messages doesn't have subject), but don't know any MySQL code to do UNION GROUP BY of the sort. Is it possible to do this in one query without having to parse all the conversation_id in PHP and then load the messages accordingly?

Comment: Why do you need the rows with 'null' values? Is it really necessary ? Why don't you just repeat the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can do this with 1 query that contains a sub-query like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT Conversation_id 
    FROM Participants 
    WHERE User_id = 1 AND Ignored = 0
    GROUP BY Conversation_id
) AS C_IDs 
INNER JOIN Conversations AS C ON C_IDs.Conversation_id = C.Conversation_id
INNER JOIN Messages AS M ON C_IDs.Conversation_id = M.Conversation_id
WHERE C_IDs.Conversation_id = 1
```

This should return a result like:

```
C_IDs.Conversation_id   C.Conversation_id   C.Subject   M.Message_id    M.Message_text  M.From_user_id  M.Date  M.Conversation_ID
1                       1                   'random'    1               'a'             1                       1
1                       1                   'random'    2               'b'             2                       1
1                       1                   'random'    3               'c'             5                       1
```

If you remove the WHERE clause at the end and change up the SELECT:

```
SELECT C.Conversation_id AS Conversation_id, C.Subject AS Subject, M.Message_id AS Message_id, M.Message_text AS Message_text, M.From_user_id AS From_user_id
FROM (
    SELECT Conversation_id 
    FROM Participants 
    WHERE User_id = 1 AND Ignored = 0
    GROUP BY Conversation_id
) AS C_IDs 
INNER JOIN Conversations AS C ON C_IDs.Conversation_id = C.Conversation_id
INNER JOIN Messages AS M ON C_IDs.Conversation_id = M.Conversation_id
```

The result should be like this:

```
Conversation_id Subject     Message_id  Message_text    From_user_id
1               'random'    1           'a'             1
1               'random'    2           'b'             2
1               'random'    3           'c'             5
8               'yolo'      5           'e'             1
```

If you are looping through this in a result set, simply create a variable that tracks the conversation id. Initialize the value to NULL, then add an if statement that checks if the value has changed. If it has, then write out the new conversation details, then set the id to the new id.

Comment: Great answer, well explained and also gave a better way of running the result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's a really bad way IMHO. Instead of messing it up that much, just do 2 simple queries. First query for the conversation, second query for all messages related to the conversations. Assuming you are using PDO, here are the two needed queries:

```
$q1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT Conversation_ID FROM `participants` WHERE `User_id` = ? AND `Ignored` = 0');

$q1->execute(array($userID));

$conversations = array_map(function($item) { return $item->Conversation_ID; }, $q1->fetchAll());

$q2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `Conversation_ID` IN (' . implode(',', $conversations) . ') AND `User_id` != ?');

$q2->execute(array($userID));

$messages = $q2->fetchAll();
```

At this point, `$messages` contain every info you want except for conversation topics, but you can find those topics in what returns from `$q1->fetchAll()`.